# When setting data fields in Python objects, should I use the "self" keyword?

Tags: python

Should I write

```
class MyClass:
     def __init__(self):
         self.field = 0
```

or

```
class MyClass:
     def __init__(self):
         field = 0
```

Is there any difference between these statements?

Comment: I'm don't think the latter sets `MyClass.field`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you *must* use the `self` variable to set the properties of Python objects/instances.

In the second case, you're just creating a local variable in `__init__`, not defining a property.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        field = 0

print MyClass().field # an error! it's not defined!
```

You may be misled by the way that you can just use raw assignments in `class` blocks to set class properties:

```
class MyClass:
    a = 2

print MyClass.a # 2
```

The behaviour in `class` blocks is unusual, and you don't get similar behaviour inside methods.

Answer (score 3):

The first chunk of code creates an instance attribute that can be accessed once an instance of the class has been created:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.field
0
```

The scope of the second chunk's `field` variable is only within the `__init__` function, so accessing the variable outside of that scope won't work:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.field
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: MyClass instance has no attribute 'field'
```

Answer (score 0):

The former sets the value as a property of the class. The latter, as simply a local variable.

If elsewhere in your program you do

```
foo = MyClass();
print foo.field;
```

The print statement above will only work with the first code snippet, not with the second.